# Using the if and else statement to change my fare rate

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have this so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class two {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("--- Stage 1 Taxi Fare Calculator ---");

        Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );

        System.out.print("Enter in pick up time:  ");
        System.out.flush();
        String startTime = user_input.next();

        System.out.print("Enter in pickup point:  ");
        System.out.flush();
        String pickUp = user_input.next();

        System.out.print("Enter in drop off point:  ");
        System.out.flush();
        String dropOff = user_input.next();

        System.out.print("Enter in trip distance in km:  ");
        System.out.flush();
        Double tripDist = user_input.nextDouble();
        user_input.nextLine();

        Double fareRate = 1.60;
        Double baseFare = tripDist * fareRate;
        Double totalFare = baseFare;

        String m1 = "The pickup point was: %15s%n";
        String m2 = "The drop off point was: %13s%n";
        String m3 = "The pickup time was: %11s%n";
        String m4 = "Estimated distance (km): %12f%n";
        String m5 = "Fare Charged: $%11.2f%n";
        String m6 = "Base fare: $%15.2f%n";
        String m7 = "Total fare: $%14.2f%n";
        String m8 = "Plus surcharges: $%14.2f%n";
        System.out.println(" --- Taxi fare details --- ");
        System.out.printf(m1, pickUp); 
        System.out.printf(m2, dropOff);
        System.out.printf(m3, startTime);
        System.out.printf(m4, tripDist);
        System.out.printf(m5, fareRate);
        System.out.printf(m6, baseFare);
        System.out.printf(m7, totalFare);
    }


}
```

What I need to do is using an if and else statement is to change the fareRate depending on what time it is during the day in 24 hour time. so say its 16:00 - 18:59 the fare should be 2.00 and 00:00 - 05:59 should be 2.40. I have been fiddling around and cant seem to get anything to work. I have used if,elif and else in python but cant get the gist of it in java. Thank you once again for your help.

Comment: `if`, `elif`, and `else` in python are pretty much exactly the same in Java, with the exception that `elif` --> `else if` (and the fact that you use braces for scope instead of whitespace, but that's not limited to `if`/`else`). If you can write the requisite if/else structure in Python, converting it to Java should be straightforward.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: you don't need to always flush the Scanner.

Comment: I suggest you only use `Double` if you want the value to be `null`, otherwise use `double` which cannot be `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the most optimal solution, but I'm trying to show how can you parse and compare time with core java functions without java 8 enhancements.

First you need a parser to convert your string to Date object then I created the boundaries for comparison (maybe the start of the interval is not fit and you need to change 16:00 to 15:59, etc...).

This is a demonstration only solution and in Java 8 the solution is different, but I hope it helps you understand the if,else-if, else structure better.

you just need to change this:

```
Double fareRate = 1.60;
```

to:

```
Double fareRate = getFareRate(startTime);
```

and change your

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
```

The function:

```
  private static double getFareRate(String startTime) throws ParseException {

        SimpleDateFormat timeFormatParser = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        // 
        Date peakTimeStart = timeFormatParser.parse("16:00");
        Date peakTimeEnd = timeFormatParser.parse("19:00");
        Date nightStart = timeFormatParser.parse("0:00");
        Date nightEnd = timeFormatParser.parse("6:00");
        //
        Date startTimeAsDate = timeFormatParser.parse(startTime);
        if (startTimeAsDate.after(peakTimeStart) && startTimeAsDate.before(peakTimeEnd)) {
            return 2d;
        } else if (startTimeAsDate.after(nightStart) && startTimeAsDate.before(nightEnd)) {
            return 2.4d;
        } else {
            return 1.6d;
        }
    }
```